# Redirect in Centos 6

Tags: apache, centos6

I have a site running on an apache server, and I'm trying to redirect the user to the main page by just typing the ip, such as this:

1.2.3.4 brings you to 1.2.3.4/my/website/main/page

How do you do that, and which is the best way?

Apparently it's pretty easy, but the guides and documentation I've found are kinda confusing, and since it's my time doing this, I'm pretty lost.

Comment: You can use mod_rewrite in your apache configuration to write rewrite rule, see here - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to append this to your configuration file:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /my/website/main/page
```

mod_rewrite not required.

Comment: Yup this worked, thanks man. While it can be found in the documentation, it's incredibly confusing for someone who hasn't dealt with apache...